# Copy access database back-end from network drive to local folder on load

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm writing an MS access program with the back-end split out into a separate file. I would like to store the back-end on a network drive but without the downsides (slowing everything down, risk of corruption from unreliable network connection).

The database will only have 3 users, so it's fine to lock the database when someone is using it.

My plan is to store the back-end on a network drive, and copy it to the user's local directory on load. On exit I'll copy the database back.

(I'll record in a text file on the network drive that the back-end is in use and lock other users out. On exit I'll make it check that nothing has gone wrong and the database is still locked to this user before copying it back etc etc.)

My question is, is it possible to get access to use a back-end database which doesn't exist when the front-end first loads? The first thing I want to do on load is copy the database from the network to a local folder and then load that up as the back end. Is that possible? Access' AutoExec doesn't seem to let me do that, what other options are there?

(Also, if my plan is utterly stupid please let me know!)

Thanks

Comment: Where is the network drive? In the same building or elsewhere? If it is a LAN, you should not have any problems leaving the back-end on the network. The scenario you propose is much more liable to failures. I have back-end on servers that have run for a considerable number of years without any problems. You just need to be a little careful.

Comment: The network drive is not in the same building, so I don't have the nice speedy connection of a local LAN. I think the connection is likely to be via a VPN, but I can't guarantee that.

Comment: Depending on the reliability of your users, wouldn't it be almost as simple to just uses a joined database (front end and back end together) and have the users take the file when they are going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - as long as your frontend refrains from opening a linked table until the copy is ready.
You can even let the frontend itself copy the file with the FileCopy command.

However, your approach will fail miserably that day two users miss each other or if the copy fails.
A much better route would be to upsize the backend to SQL Server Express (which is free) and install this on a server at either location.

For this scenario, the server hardware could be just any realiable machine running Windows XP/2003+, though I would recommend Windows 7/2008 as a minimum.